# Using Angular Signals with HostBinding to update style?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-signals

In a `app-test` component I have the following:

```
  @Input( { transform: booleanAttribute})
  reverse: boolean = false;

  @HostBinding('style.flex-direction')
  direction: string = this.reverse ? 'column-reverse' : 'column';
```

And so if the designer applies the `reverse` attribute to `app-test` like this:

```
<app-test reverse></app-test>
```

Then Angular should set `style="flex-direction: column-reverse"` on the `app-test` element.

And I'm wondering how to use Angular signals so that when `reverse` is set to true, direction will be set to `column-reverse`.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is being discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53888). Currently the combination of `@HostBinding` and signals is not supported.

The workaround for this is to use a getter:

```
reverse = input.required<boolean>();

@HostBinding('attr.style.flex-direction')
get direction() { return this.reverse() ? 'column-reverse' : 'column' }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: 'My name (red is {{ red() }})',
})
export class AppChildComponent {
  red = input(false);

  @HostBinding('style.color')
  get color() {
    return this.red() ? 'red' : 'green';
  }
}
```

And in the container component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AppChildComponent],
  template: `
    <app-child [red]="true"></app-child>
  `,
})
export class App {
}
```

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hostbinding-signal)

Answer (score 0):

My current project was on Angular 16, so this is what I ended up with (Since `input` is for Angular 17+):

```
  @Input( { transform: booleanAttribute})
  reverse:boolean = false;

  @HostBinding('style.flex-direction')
  get direction() { return this.reverse ? 'column-reverse' : 'column' }
```